# asp.net textbox, want to dynamically change from single line to multiline when full

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can't find an answer to this question for the life of me, despite how common I'd expect it to be.

But I have a form, all textboxes are currently single line, and 90% of the time that suffices for the needs of this form.  In some cases, submissions require larger text entries, and the request I've been given is that, for the sake of form aesthetics, textboxes remain as single line unless text fills it, in which case it dynamically changes to multiline.

Is such a thing possible?  I'd like to have some sort of event, preferably using c# codebehind, where when a certain amount of characters is exceeded, or when text exceeds the width of the textbox, that it converts to multiline.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily make them all multiline, but specified with one row.

Then capture the length when typing in a JS event, and if over your specified length then add rows to it.

```
//pseudo code
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="1" onchange="resizeBox(this)"></asp:TextBox>

function resizeBox(el){
    if (el.value.length > 20 && el.rows == 1)
        el.rows = 4;
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I'll try that tomorrow.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Absolutely, along with the green check if it works :)